# How to show overflow on textfield's value (ellipsis)

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I achieve something like this?
That the textfields value is showing (...) when text is bigger than the remaining space

When the text input

I know we can use `overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,` in a Text widget. How can we do something similar in textfield value?

[image]

Comment: If you wrap you textfield on a SizedBox or a Container with a fixed width will not do the trick?

Comment: No, it wouldn’t show the three dots.

Comment: Can you include what you've tried so far?

Comment: Try clip behaviour. But its not same as ellipsis

Comment: How can I do that? @KaushikChandru

Comment: Include tech stack in question text

Answer (score 0):

i think for now ,there is no parameter to set overflow on `TextField`

since the issue still open on official repository [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/61069).

maybe you can use another plugin like [auto_size_text_field](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text_field)

```
AutoSizeTextField(
  controller: _controller,
  overflowReplacement: Text(
  _controller.text,
  style: const TextStyle(overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
),
```

Comment: actually you can create your own widget.  following the concept of `autosizetextfield`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But this package has a lot of errors and doesn't seem to be something useful in a project. Like when I type is, sometimes out of nowhere the field that I'm importing from the package gets removed in widget tree for no reason

Answer (score 0):

My workaround is to transfer the typed text to `hintText`, and then clear the text in the controller so that the `hintText` is visible:

```
TextField(
  onChanged: (text) => onTextChanged(text),
  onTapOutside: (event) => textEditingController.text = "",
  controller: textEditingController,
  decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(
    hintText: hintText,
  ),
),

void onTextChanged(text){
  hintText = text;
}
```

When you click outside the box the ellipses appear (please ignore the `70` and `100`):

[image: textfield-overflow]